# Modeling a crease on a helmet

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a helmet from a 2D image but can't figure out which way to go about making this crease. I started with a UV sphere and mirrored it then started to drag faces to create the general shape which worked great but as soon as I started on this crease I got stuck.  Any suggestions on if I should start from a different object or how a more experienced modeler might go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You want an edge loop to follow that crease. Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Hay Charles thanks for throwing this my way!